# On demand ad hoc counters

Tags: macros, counters

Is it possible to define a command `\mycounter{<par>}` in LaTeX which does the following:

- if a counter with name `<par>` exists then increment the value of that counter and print the counter's current value;
- if no counter with name `<par>` exists then create a new counter named `<par>` with value `1` and print the current value of `<par>`?

Comment: Defining counters on the fly is not always a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generates the counter on the fly although this is not recommended in any case.

If the counter name given as first argument already exists, there is a command `\c@#1` already which is LaTeX representation of a counter (well, top layer on `\count....` registers actually.

If `\@undefined{c@#1}` is true, define the new counter and set it to one, displaying with `\csname the#1\endcsname`, i.e. `\thefoo` for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\counteronthefly}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
    \newcounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{#1}{1}%
    \csname the#1\endcsname% print it
  }{%
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    \csname the#1\endcsname% print it
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\section{First}

section counter exist -- increase and show: \counteronthefly{section}

foo counter does not exist -- define, set to zero and show: \counteronthefly{foo}

foo counter does exist now -- increase and show: \counteronthefly{foo}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you already have `@` a letter you can use `\@nameuse{the#1}` instead of `\csname the#1\endcsname`…

Comment: @clemens: I rarely use `\@nameuse` -- it's a command out of my everyday's need

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why you say generating counters on the fly is not good practice?

Comment: @Ubiquitous: There might be occasions where the generation on the fly might screw up the counter register system